# Perl mail format with new line

Tags: regex, perl

Hi am writing a perl script were am doing push(@var1,$var2) in @var the values will be get stored and am passing that array value in mail like system("echo @var1| mail -s \"perlmailformat\"  xyz.perlmonks\@example.com");.Hence am success in getting mail but values are clubbed each other with out any new lines .Please let me know how to make a mail format in script or sysntax

Answer (score 1):

You are interpolating the `@var1` into a shell command which is an extremely unsafe thing to do. It also prints all items in the array on the same line, because interpolating an array into a string joins all items with a single space (and the `echo` command simply prints all it's arguments onto a single line, with spaces in between and a single newline at the end).

You want to `open` a pipe to the `mail` command:

```
my $subject = "perlmailformat";
my $address = "xyz@example.com";

# open a pipe to "mail"
open my $mail, "|-", "mail", "-s" => $subject, $address
  or die "Can't open mail command: $!";

# print each line:
print { $mail } "$_\n" for @var1;

# close the pipe
close $mail or die "Couldn't send mail: $!";
```

This completely circumvents the shell, and is thus much safer.

Answer (score -1):

Push a newline into the array before passing the same to the mail command.

```
push @var,"\n";
system("echo \"@var\" | mail -s \"perlmailformat\" xyz.perlmonks\@example.com");
```